# Making multiple of the same components using different props generating unexpected results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the code I am having trouble with, the goal is to add a room to the beginning of the list.

```
 render(){
         return(
            <>
 this.state.Rooms.map((room,i)=>
                        <li key={i}>
                        <p> {room.length}  {room.width}</p>
                        <Room  length={room.length} width ={room.width}/>
                        </li>
                    )
</>
}
```

The output of displaying 3 rooms like this is as follows

```
37 1

This is a room, it has a length of 35 and a width of 1

36 1

This is a room, it has a length of 35 and a width of 1

35 1

This is a room, it has a length of 35 and a width of 1
```

It should be

```
37 1

This is a room, it has a length of 37 and a width of 1

36 1

This is a room, it has a length of 36 and a width of 1

35 1

This is a room, it has a length of 35 and a width of 1
```

The array is populated using the code

```
        let newRooms = [];
        newRooms.push({length:this.state.StreetNumber,width:1});      
        this.state.Rooms.forEach((room)=>
          newRooms.push(room)
        ) 

        this.setState((state)=>({
                        Rooms: newRooms
        }));
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: While this has nothing to do with your issue, using map like this is an anti pattern. If you aren't returning anything in your callback or if you aren't using the returned array you should be using forEach and not map.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put *components* into state, it can result in confusing behavior and convoluted code, like what you're encountering here. Instead, put primitives, objects, and arrays into state, and then in the render method, transform that into the required JSX.

Here, it looks like the best approach would be to have an array of objects, where each object has a `StreetNumber` property and a `width` property.

```
this.setState({
  rooms: [
    { StreetNumber: 35, width: 1 },
    { StreetNumber: 36, width: 1 },
    { StreetNumber: 37, width: 1 },
  ]
});
```

And then you can render it:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.rooms.map(({ StreetNumber, width }) => (
          <Room {...{ StreetNumber, width }} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or something along those lines.

To add a room to the state and to what's rendered, just do something like

```
this.setState({
  rooms: [...this.state.rooms, { StreetNumber: 38, width: 1 }]
});
```

Live demo:

```js
const Room = ({ StreetNumber }) => <div>{StreetNumber}</div>

class App extends React.Component {
    state = { rooms: [] }
    render() {
        return (<div>
            {this.state.rooms.map(({ StreetNumber, width }) => (
                <Room {...{ StreetNumber, width }} />
            ))}
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({
                rooms: [...this.state.rooms, { StreetNumber: 38, width: 1 }]
            })}>add room</button>
        </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, tried it.

Comment: Works just fine here - see live demo

Comment: Live demo just proves the bug, 38 over and over again for no reason

Comment: That's because that's what the click handler does - the item it appends is `{ StreetNumber: 38, width: 1 }`. If you change that, you'll see it change in the render too. It's just a demo, I don't know where your numbers come from. Feel free to use `Math.random` or something if you just want to check that it works.

Comment: It has to be dynamic, the street number changes as you press the button

Comment: Then feel free to implement that logic as desired. This approach does solve what you were asking about - the solution is to not put components into state, but to put serializable values into state.

Answer (score -1):

The following code has to be added to the Room component

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setState({ length : props.length , width : props.width });  
      }
```